# Rails 6 Nginx reverse proxy: problem serving static files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have been through several posts to find a solution to my problem: all but js scripts seem to be served by Nginx as reverse proxy.

I have a standard monolith Rails 6 app running on localhost. As a first step before load balancing containers, I start to configure Nginx to serve static files.

On the Rails side (in development mode), I set `config.public_file_server.enabled =  false` and run  `rails assets:precompile` so that it builds `/public/assets` and `/public/pack/` folders with timestamped files.

Nginx config file is shown below: the test `nginx -t` is ok. I run the nginx service and start `rails s` listening to port 3000. Then I open localhost:8080 (or localhost:3000) and I get a 404 in the browser:

GET //localhost:8080/packs/js/application-c294f00fc4a07bb438b5.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

The other static files of type `css` or `jpg` are correctly fetched whilst js script aren't. The Nginx access.log shows:

GET /assets/application.debug-(timestamp).css HTTP/1.1" 200

GET /assets/db-schema-(timestamp).jpg HTTP/1.1" 200

GET /packs/js/application-c294f00fc4a07bb438b5.js HTTP/1.1" 404

but nothing in the error.log.

What am I doing wrong?

The Nginx config is:

```
#/nginx.conf
worker_processes  auto; 
worker_rlimit_nofile 1024;
error_log  /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/error.log warn;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    # accept_mutex on;        # "on" if nginx worker_processes > 1
}


http {
    include           mime.types;
    default_type      application/octet-stream;
    sendfile          on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    
    add_header    X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header    X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header    X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    
    include /servers*.;
    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/rails.conf;
}
```

and

```
#rails.conf

#upstream app {
#   server http://localhost:3000;
#}

server {
    listen          8080;
    server_name     localhost;

    gzip                  on;
    gzip_proxied          no-cache no-store private expired auth;
    gzip_types
        "application/json;charset=utf-8" application/json ..."
        
    
    location ~ ^/(assets|packs)/{
        try_files $uri @rails;
        access_log off;
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        add_header Last-Modified "";
        add_header ETag "";
        break;
    }

    location / { 
        try_files $uri @rails;  
    }

    location @rails {    
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;    
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;         
        proxy_set_header  Host $host;    
        
        proxy_pass        http://localhost:3000; # http://app

        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Connection ‘’;
        proxy_buffering     off;
        proxy_cache         off;
        chunked_transfer_encoding off;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ok, I found the problem. I had to add to the server the root:

```
root  /path-to-my-public-folder/public;
```

and performance is ok. Now, I don't see why Nginx found the css and jpg but not the scripts.